# Converting midnight in to a date time format in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, time, type-conversion

I have a very specific problem. I have been trying to convert a date time character into a date time format in R. Example: "2017-05-21 00:00:00".
Whenever I try to convert it using strptime and as.POSIXct to a date time format it gives me "2017-05-21".

Thanks for any help

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Try: `as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 00:00:00",format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')+1` to see that while it only shows you `"2017-05-21 CEST"`, the time part is included but just omitted from the output.

Comment: That datetime is 1495339200 seconds after 1970-01-01 and what you see printed is just a matter of human-readable formatting. Sort of like if you enter `(x <- 1.000000000)` the output is just `1`.

Answer (score 4):

As @ngm says, this is only a formatting choice on the part of R. You can check to make sure it's actually midnight.  Datetimes are stored as seconds past the epoch, and can actually be used in arithmetic.

```
t1 <- as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 00:00:00")
t1
# [1] "2017-05-21 EDT"

as.integer(t1)
# [1] 1495339200
```

So your time is 1,495,339,200 seconds after the epoch. Now we can look at midnight plus one second.

```
t2 <- as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 00:00:01")
t2
# [1] "2017-05-21 00:00:01 EDT"

as.integer(t2)
# [1] 1495339201
```

Which is one second higher than `t1`. So `t1` is, in fact, midnight.

Comment: So R should realise when it converts "2017-05-21 00:00:00" to a date time format that if it shows "2017-05-21" it's at midnight on that day?

Comment: R doesn't show all the zeros because it doesn't think they'd be helpful, so it's up to us to know it means midnight. Again, like @ngm pointed out, it "strips" the trailing time portion when it's all zeros (i.e., midnight). With `t1` from my example, if you print `c(t1, t2)`, it will print the zeros for the first value.  The difference is in formatting, not the data.

Comment: But if I need to compare two date times surely not having the zeros there will impact the result?

Comment: No, it won't.  The underlying data is not what's being shown when printed.  `print` just gives us a nice-looking blurb of text meant for humans to understand.  Try `identical(t1, as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 00:00:00"))`, and you'll see they're the same.